# Encountering an 'Unable to resolve module styled-components/native' error in my Expo React Native project

Tags: javascript, react-native, module, expo, styled-components

I'm encountering an issue in my Expo React Native project and I've exhausted my troubleshooting options. Here's the problem and what I've done so far:

Problem Description:
I'm facing an error that prevents my project from running. The error message is as follows:

Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 60
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=60):
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Operation timed out
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=60):
The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out
Operation timed out
iOS Bundling failed 1824ms
Unable to resolve "styled-components/native" from "App.js"

What I've Tried:

- I've installed the 'styled-components' package and verified its presence in the 'node_modules' folder.
- I've checked my project's configuration, which includes 'package.json,' 'app.json,' and 'babel.config.js' (see code samples below).
- I've ensured the correct import statement in 'App.js':

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components/native";


Here is a snippet of my App.js file:

import { StatusBar as ExpoStatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components/native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import {
  useFonts as useOswald,
  Oswald_400Regular,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/oswald";
import { useFonts as useLato, Lato_400Regular } from "@expo-google-fonts/lato";

import { theme } from "./src/infrastructure/theme";
import { RestaurantsScreen } from "./src/features/restaurants/screens/restaurants.screen";
import { SafeArea } from "./src/components/utility/safe-area.component";

Here are the relevant dependencies in ‘package.json’:

"dependencies": {
  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
  "expo": "^49.0.13",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.72.5",
  "react-native-styled-components": "^2.1.0",
  "uuid": "^9.0.1"
}

My ‘babel.config.js’ file:

module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};

Additional Notes:
*I was told, You must import ThemeProvide form the styled-components directly:import {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components';
So i did this and it still does not render as desired. 
* I've tried various troubleshooting steps, including clearing caches and restarting the Metro Bundler, to no avail.
I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error. Thank you!
```

Comment: In your package.json  there is a package called react-native-styled-components

but if you install it should be something like this:     "styled-components": "^6.1.0",

Install package from https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components